# Editing a dictionary with a QTreeView

Tags: python, dictionary, pyqt, qtreeview

I have a reduced code sample in which a window is created with just one <kbd>Button</kbd>.

[image]

Pressing it will pop a Qt dialog `TestDialog` which takes as parameter a Python dictionary. This dictionary is displayed in an editable `QTreeView` inside the dialog.

[image]

After changing some values you can click on <kbd>Ok</kbd> or <kbd>Cancel</kbd> to either accept or discard the changes. Once the dialog is closed my intention is to retrieve from the main window the modified dictionary calling `dialog.get_data()` which, right now only returns the original unmodified dictionary. After clicking the <kbd>Ok</kbd> button, the retrieved dictionary is printed to stdout.

My question is, how can I modify the dictionary when the tree view is modified? Is there a way to automatically attach a function to be executed on each item modification? So that when editing, for example, a `float` in the tree view, then the corresponding value will be updated as float in the dictionary?

The dictionary does not have a fixed size and the types on it may change. The list of types is limited and known though and, for this example, could be reduced to {`int`, `str`, `float`, `Other`}. It can be assumed as well that the parents are not supposed to be editable and the children are only editable in the second column, just as it is shown in the example bellow.

Here is the code I have:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic
from copy import deepcopy


class TestDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, data):

        super(TestDialog, self).__init__()

        self.data = deepcopy(data)

        # Layout
        btOk = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")
        btCancel = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.tree = QtGui.QTreeView()
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(btOk)
        hbox.addWidget(btCancel)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 400)

        # Button signals
        btCancel.clicked.connect(self.reject)
        btOk.clicked.connect(self.accept)

        # Tree view
        self.tree.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel())
        self.tree.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tree.setHeaderHidden(False)
        self.tree.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectItems)

        self.tree.model().setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Parameter', 'Value'])

        for x in self.data:
            if not self.data[x]:
                continue
            parent = QtGui.QStandardItem(x)
            parent.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags)
            for y in self.data[x]:
                value = self.data[x][y]
                child0 = QtGui.QStandardItem(y)
                child0.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags |
                                QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                child1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))
                child1.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled |
                                QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable |
                                ~ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
                parent.appendRow([child0, child1])
            self.tree.model().appendRow(parent)

        self.tree.expandAll()

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

class Other(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return '(%s, %s)' % (self.x, self.y)

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super(Example, self).__init__()

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.clicked.connect(self.show_dialog)

        self.data = {}
        # This example will be hidden (has no parameter-value pair)
        self.data['example0'] = {}
        # A set example with an integer and a string parameters
        self.data['example1'] = {}
        self.data['example1']['int'] = 14
        self.data['example1']['str'] = 'asdf'
        # A set example with a float and other non-conventional type
        self.data['example2'] = {}
        self.data['example2']['float'] = 1.2
        self.data['example2']['other'] = Other(4, 8)

    def show_dialog(self):
        dialog = TestDialog(self.data)
        accepted = dialog.exec_()
        if not accepted:
            return
        self.data = deepcopy(dialog.get_data())
        print self.data


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to the model's [itemChanged](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#itemChanged) signal:

```
    self.tree.model().itemChanged.connect(self.handleItemChanged)
```

The handler would look something like this:

```
    def handleItemChanged(self, item):
        parent = self.data[item.parent().text()]
        key = item.parent().child(item.row(), 0).text()
        parent[key] = type(parent[key])(item.text())
```

Note that the conversion of values using `type` won't necessarily work for custom classes like `Other`. So you will have to either ensure that the constructor for such classes can convert a string representation, or parse the string into the appropriate arguments before passing them to the constructor.

Also note that I haven't bothered to deal with `QString` values in the above example code. If you use Python 3, this is not an issue, because they are automatically converted to/from Python strings by default. But for Python 2, you can switch this behaviour on by doing the following:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic
```

For more details on this, see [Selecting Incompatible APIs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html) in the [PyQt4 Docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/).